# Printing dynamic components using AS3 PrintJob

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I am trying to print dynamically created spark components using PrintJob (not FlexPrintJob). The problem is it prints blank when I pass the component to PrintJob e.g.:

printJob.addPage(component as Sprite, null, pjo); - component is dynamically created.
printJob.send();

How can I make the component and its contents available?

Any and every response will be really appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Your components must be rendered on screen if you want to be able to print them.

Comment: Hi RIAstar, thanks for your comment. Is it possible to print the component without rendering it?

Comment: Not to my knowledge. But I think if you render them, print them and then remove them from the displaylist again, you won't even see the rendering. If this results in flickering you could try rendering in an area of the screen that is invisible to the user (not sure if that'll work though).

Comment: Thanks RIAstar, I've tried that but problem is it prints the original component label but not the labels I dynamically added. I used a popup to implement the solution you suggested.

Comment: You do have to make sure the components are completely rendered before you start the print job. If you're dynamically adding them, this means that you'll have to listen for FlexEvent.CREATION_COMPLETE on all the dynamically added components. You might want to consider using a DataGroup to render your components instead of dynamically adding them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your help is appreciated. I've found a solution (although its not what I wanted). What I did is I generated my component using Sprite and TextField and then I printed it using PrintJob not FlexPrintJob

Answer (score 0):

paren, convert your components into a bitmapdata, create an invisible bitmap that is added to canvas, attach the bitmapdata into it, draw the bitmapdata into a new sprite and pass that into your printjob. thats how I got it working on my own proj.

Comment: Hi stephen, thanks for your response, let me give it a try. Would you share some of your printing code with me if it's fine please.

Comment: maybe this will help: http://blog.kreatx.com/2011/11/11/flex-printing-print-preview-pdf-generation/

Comment: also if you are sure your Sprite really does contain the items to be printed, do you have    options = new PrintJobOptions();
   options.printAsBitmap = true;

Comment: No luck Stephen, still printing a blank page. I need to do this. I'll have to play with the code a little. Thanks for your help.